# Quick and easy way to setup Codedeploy for CodeIgniter on Bitbucket?

Tags: codeigniter, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitbucket, aws-code-deploy

Can someone please direct me to a simple, quick and easy way to setup a CodeIgniter project (hosted via Bitbucket) with AWS CodeDeploy?

Comment: Describe steps how did you do it and post error messages you are getting after that way of install.